# Need help writing code modifying the contents of a txt file and then saving it as a dictionary in a json file (it contains sentiment data)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some sentences saved in a txt file along with their corresponding sentiment. It is intended to train machine learning classifiers. However, I want to restructure the contents of the txt file and then save it as a json. Below I will explain the before and after structure I want.

The txt file is saved in the following format:

```
FIRST LINE OF TEXT .@negative
SECOND LINE OF TEXT .@neutral
```

As you can tell, each sentence is saved on a separate line, followed by a single space, followed by a delimiter (.@ in this case) followed by the assigned sentiment for the sentence.

Here is the format I want in the json file:

```
[{'message_body': 'FIRST LINE OF TEXT', 'sentiment': -1}, {'message_body': 'SECOND LINE OF TEXT', 'sentiment': 0}]
```

So here we have an open bracket followed by a dictionary with 2 keys (message body and sentiment) where the message body key contains the sentence of text and the sentiment key contains the numeric value of the sentiment (negative being -1, positive being 1 and neutral being 0). Thus it is in effect saved as a list of dictionaries, each dictionary corresponding to 1 line in the original txt file.

Does anyone know of a way I could write code to do this for me? I'm assuming it would be some kind of for loop, but dictionaries aren't my forte. Thanks in advance!

Edit: figured out a somewhat long-winded way to do this after saving the txt file as a csv:

```
import pandas as pd

data_csv = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='text.csv' , sep='.@', header=None, names=['sentence','sentiment'])

list_data = []

for index, row in data_csv.iterrows():

    dictionary_data = {}
    dictionary_data['message_body'] = row['sentence']
    if row['sentiment'] == 'positive':
         dictionary_data['sentiment'] = 1
    elif row['sentiment'] == 'negative':
         dictionary_data['sentiment'] = -1
    else:
         dictionary_data['sentiment'] = 0
    list_data.append(dictionary_data)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried anything, I just have the txt file saved in a folder. I'm not sure where to start, that's why I came here. I'm new to stack overflow, is it necessary to have some starter code to ask a question? Thanks!

Comment: Take a read at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read the file, you should be able to do this as a list comprehension, e.g.

```
list = [{'message_body': line_without_sentiment, 'sentiment': sentiment} for line in file]
```

I will leave reading the file, parsing the body from the sentiment, and writing the JSON file as Google exercises.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
# read the file into a list of lines
with open("input.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# set up empty dictionary
rv = []

# for each line, split into text and sentiment
for x in lines:
    line_dict = {'message_body': x.split('.@')[0].strip()}
    value = x.split('.@')[1].strip()
    # Apply sentiment logic
    if value == 'positive':
        line_dict['sentiment'] = 1
    elif value == 'negative':
        line_dict['sentiment'] = -1
    else:
        line_dict['sentiment'] = 0
    rv.append(line_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> rv
[{'message_body': 'FIRST LINE OF TEXT', 'sentiment': -1},
 {'message_body': 'SECOND LINE OF TEXT', 'sentiment': 0}]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, I had a quick quesiton. You suggested splitting on '.' but some of the text has periods in the text (for instance as a decimal point). Would this work if I split on '.@' and then don't include the @ in the if/elif/else statement? Like this:
```
for x in lines:
    key, value = x.split('.@')[0].strip(), x.split('.@')[1].strip()

    # apply sentiment logic and add value to dictionary
    if value == 'positive':
        rv[key] = 1
    elif value == 'negative':
        rv[key] = -1
    else:
        rv[key] = 0
```

Comment: @NorePatel I've updated my answer with your modification.

Comment: Thanks so much, going to try it out :) Can let you know if it works

Comment: I have gotten an error. IndexError: list index out of range.
It occurs on this line: ```---> 12     key, value = x.split('.@')[0].strip(), x.split('.@')[1].strip()```
Any Ideas on what might be wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: That suggests that '.@' didn't occur in the line.

Comment: Some more info, the txt file does seem to read correctly. The lines object is a list of strings, each string corresponding to each line in the original txt file, followed by a newline \n. So basically it is 'text from first line .@negative\n', 'text from second line .@neutral\n' etc, Not sure if this info helps. The .@ is definitely in each line, but it is immediately followed by the sentiment without any space in between and this is also connected to the \n newline symbol. Could that be the issue?

Comment: The only place an `IndexError` could occur is if `x.split('.@')` returns a list with only one entry - i.e. if there is no `'.@'` in the line. Can you add a `print(x)` above that line, and see what the last line printed before the error is?

Comment: Hey again :) So I finally got it to work, but there were several aspects that weren't what I intended. It ended up outputting just 1 dictionary with every sentence as the key and every sentiment as the value. What I wanted though was for there to be 2 keys, one titled "message_body" which would have values as the sentences, and the second key titled "sentiment" which would have the numeric sentiment as its values. In this method, each sentence would be it's own dictionary (each dictionary having only 2 keys) and the whole document would end up being a list of dictionaries. Any ideas for this?

Comment: Updated my answer to match that specification :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I ended up created another method that "kind of" worked. I imported the data into a pandas df and then used a for loop to create the list of dictionaries (I included the code above). It seems to have the same output for both, although when I used a boolean to check if they were the same, it came back false lol, not sure why. But seems right in both cases, thanks again!